# How can we hide the parent's theme url at the child themes details on a multisite?

Tags: themes, admin, child-theme

I hope the title makes sense.

But anyway, to clear things up, here is a screen shoot of what I mean:

[image]

To be honest I really don't see how site admins benefit from this piece of information since they cannot edit the files.

I have tried using:

```
div.themedetaildiv p {
    display:none !important;
}
```

but it hides everything and NOT just the second paragraph.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to work it out myself, after reading a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958012/hide-long-text-except-the-first-two-paragraphs) over at the **Stackoverflow Site**:

```
div.themedetaildiv > p:nth-child(n+3) { display:none; }
```

Which means: we go to the theme details and hide all paragraphs after the second one. The first one being the version number of the theme (Version: 1.4.2).

Hope it helps someone else.